# How can I extract data from a 3rd party application's UI controls?

Tags: windows, clipboard

In 2003 I found a little utility which allowed me to select a control (like a listview) on any application, and it would copy it's contents into the clipboard.

For example, you could select the list in Windows Explorer, and all the filenames, sizes, dates, etc. would be copied for you to paste into Notepad.

I don't remember the name of it, but I do remember the name was so unrelated that I could never find it when I needed it. So now, years later, I can't find it.

Does anybody know of any utilities which might do this? Or possibly even the utility I'm talking about?

Comment: AutoIt has this ability, to some degree anyway. It can pull this information from any standard win32 application, but has limited success with other graphical libraries. To specifically get the text of a control, you would use ControlGetText(). It isn't a full solution, as you would have to construct much of it yourself, but it is a push in the right direction if you're willing to script it out.

Comment: @Ramhound Don't take that "rule" too seriously please. Many questions are based on real issues and can be easily made constructive. Product suggestions are – for example – considered off topic when it's clear that there's lack of research effort or a plethora of tools available already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, the software I was looking for is called Count Characters and is available at http://www.funduc.com/countchars.htm

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to work anymore.  At least not on the 64 bit Windows 7 machine I tested it on.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds a lot like NirSoft's [SysExporter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html):

> SysExporter utility allows you to grab the data stored in standard list-views, tree-views, list boxes, combo boxes, text-boxes, and WebBrowser/HTML controls from almost any application running on your system, and export it to text, HTML or XML file.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded Count Characters v4.1 for 64 bit and it is working on Win 7 64 bit. It worked even to copy text from a listview inside a QT app !

Just my 2 cents so you guys know this tool is still working...

Comment: This should be a comment on previous answer.

Comment: I wanted to, but I am newly registered, so I can't comment on others posts.